# Groovy JsonBuilder- Capitalizing an attribute is causing an Unexpected Token error in Mule ESB

Tags: groovy, mule

I am creating a simple JSON document with a combination of Map, List, and String literal data using the JsonBuilder class in Mule ESB's Groovy Transformation step.

Here is my code that works

```
builder {
  Incident {
    number data['number']
    Solution data['close_notes']
    ClosureCode data['close_code']    
    status 'Closed'
    JournalUpdates (
      data['work_notes_list']
    )
  }
}
```

This JSON is produced

```
{
"Incident": {
    "number": "INC0011114",
    "Solution": "Returned DVD",
    "ClosureCode": "Solved (Permanently)",
    "status": "Closed",
    "JournalUpdates": [
        "Work Notes1",
        "Work Notes2"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now the weird part is when I capitalize the attribute "status", I get the error. So this code produces the error. Status is not a reserved word in Groovy but the compiler does not like it.

```
builder {
  Incident {
    number data['number']
    Solution data['close_notes']
    ClosureCode data['close_code']    
    Status 'Closed'
    JournalUpdates (
      data['work_notes_list']
    )
  }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 11: unexpected token: Closed @ line 11, column 12.
   Status 'Closed'
          ^

1 error

at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:302)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:149)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:119)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:131)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:359)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:141)
at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:107)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:236)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:160)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:843)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:548)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:524)
at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:501)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:306)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:287)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:267)
at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:214)
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.getScriptClass(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:342)
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:144)
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.compile(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:157)
at org.mule.module.scripting.component.Scriptable.initialise(Scriptable.java:169)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:271)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:154)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1391)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:439)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1188)
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.internalLookupByType(SpringRegistry.java:174)
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.lookupByType(SpringRegistry.java:167)
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.lookupObjects(SpringRegistry.java:152)
at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistryBroker.lookupObjects(AbstractRegistryBroker.java:146)
at org.mule.registry.MuleRegistryHelper.lookupObjects(MuleRegistryHelper.java:686)
at org.mule.module.apikit.Router.loadRestFlowMap(Router.java:177)
at org.mule.module.apikit.Router.initialise(Router.java:112)
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:79)
at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialiseIfInitialisable(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:314)
at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline.doInitialise(AbstractPipeline.java:208)
at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:109)
at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct$1.onTransition(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:103)
at org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager.invokePhase(AbstractLifecycleManager.java:138)
at org.mule.construct.FlowConstructLifecycleManager.fireInitialisePhase(FlowConstructLifecycleManager.java:78)
at org.mule.construct.AbstractFlowConstruct.initialise(AbstractFlowConstruct.java:102)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:85)
at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:105)
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:115)
at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:69)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:42)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:74)
at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:97)
at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:53)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:42)
at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:74)
at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:80)
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:203)
at org.mule.module.launcher.application.ApplicationWrapper.init(ApplicationWrapper.java:60)
at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultMuleDeployer.deploy(DefaultMuleDeployer.java:43)
at org.mule.tooling.server.application.ApplicationDeployer.main(ApplicationDeployer.java:127)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of these will work:

```
builder {
    Incident {
        number data['number']
        Solution data['close_notes']
        ClosureCode data['close_code']
        Status('Closed')
        JournalUpdates (
                data['work_notes_list']
                )
    }
}
```

Or:

```
builder {
    Incident {
        number data['number']
        Solution data['close_notes']
        ClosureCode data['close_code']
        'Status' 'Closed'
        JournalUpdates (
                data['work_notes_list']
                )
    }
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: I think this is applicable for all node names starting with capital letter. I am unable to build a json without using `'Foo' 'bar'`.

Comment: Yep, they both worked. Geez, I tried every combination but those two it seems. :-) Thanks for your help! I just wonder why the Solution and ClosureCode attributes do not require the same techniques.